# Many-to-many in same model

Tags: php, laravel

I need to use a many-to-many relationship to one model. I have an Article model, and I want to make a function so that other articles, typically recommended, can be attached to one article.

This is the function, it should work correctly.

```
$article = Article::where('id', $request->article_id)->first();

$articles_ids = json_decode($request->articles_ids);

$article->articles()->attach($articles_ids);
```

I have a question about how to create a table of relations in the database and in the model correctly, I did it like this, but even the migration does not work for me

Model

```
public function articles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Article');
    }

    public function article_recommended()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Models\Article');
    }
```

db

```
Schema::create('article_article_recommended', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_recommended_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('article_recommended_id')
                ->references('id')->on('article_recommended')->onDelete('set null');
            $table->unsignedBigInteger('article_id')->nullable();
            $table->foreign('article_id')
                ->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

error in migration

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1824 Failed to open the referenced table 
'article_recommended' (SQL: alter table `article_article_recommended` add constraint 
`article_article_recommended_article_recommended_id_foreign` foreign key 
(`article_recommended_id`) references `article_recommended` (`id`) on delete set null)
```

Comment: "_but even the migration does not work for me_" _What_ doesn't work? What errors do you get?

Comment: @brombeer added an error to the post

Comment: So, did you create the table `article_recommended` before? Maybe check for typos

Comment: you have `article_article_recommended` and `article_recommended` table? please check

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you trying to do should be fairly simple , it's like a following system where each user is related to many users ( same model ) but also same table !

you are here trying to create another table which i consider unnecessary , you only need two tables

`articles` & `recommendations`

and the recommendation tabel will act as a pivot table for articles with its self thus creating a many to many relationship with the same table .

###### Article.php

```php
public function recommendations() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Article::class , 'recommendations' , 'article_id' , 'recommended_article_id');
    }
```

##### create_recommendations_table.php

```
 Schema::create('recommendations', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->primary(['article_id','recommended_article_id']);
            $table->foreignId('article_id');
            $table->foreignId('recommended_article_id');
            $table->timestamps();


            $table->foreign('article_id')->references('id')->on('article')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->foreign('recommended_article_id')->references('id')->on('articles')->onDelete('cascade');
        });
```

##### usage

```
$article->recommendations()->attach($articles_ids);
```

Answer (score 0):

be sure that the ref-column has exact the same type as the source column (signed, unsigned etc.)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).